# "End-user" or "casual-user" is better for software application's user?

Tags: meaning

"End-user" is the widely accepted term, but a lot of scientific papers use "casual-user".

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: "Casual user" is a user who is not highly skilled/motivated with regard to the application in question.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume that end-user includes all users of a completed product, while casual user implies that the user does not utilize the advanced features of a product, such as debugging tools or root access.